# Find string in an array based on first word

Tags: c#, arrays, string, filter

I'm trying to filter out an array based on 2 keywords that must be in order, So far i've got this:

```
string[] matchedOne = Array.FindAll(converList, s => s.Contains(split[1]));

string[] matchedTwo = Array.FindAll(matchedOne, s => s.Contains(split[2]));

if (matchedTwo.Length == 0)
{
    Console.Clear();
    Console.WriteLine("Sorry, Your Conversion is invalid");
    Main();
}
```

converlist =

ounce,gram,28.0
ounce,fake,28.0    - Fake one I added for examples
gram, ounce, 3.0   - Fake one I added for examples
pound,ounce,16.0
pound,kilogram,0.454
pint,litre,0.568
inch, centimetre,2.5
mile,inch,63360.0

If the user types in 5, ounce, gram, When passed through "matchedOne" it would find; "once,gram,28.0" and "ounce,fake,28.0" . not those, "pound,ounce,16.0" and "gram,ounce,3.0" as it does now.

Then in "matchedTwo" it would only find "once,gram,28.0" not that and "gram,ounce,3.0"

-- Just to add: I cant use anything over "system;".

Comment: Have you considered using a class for this data, rather than comma-delimited list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var regex = new Regex(
      string.Format("^.*{0}.*{1}.*$",
      Regex.Escape(split[1]), Regex.Escape(split[2])),
      RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
      | RegexOptions.Multiline
      | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant
      | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace
      | RegexOptions.Compiled
    );

Match m = regex.Match(converlist);
```

which basically just matches a line where `split[1]` comes before `split[2]`

or without regex

```
string[] match = Array.FindAll(matchedOne, s => s.IndexOf(split[1])==-1?false: s.IndexOf(split[2], s.IndexOf(split[1])) != -1);
```

and working conversion...

```
const string converlist = "ounce,gram,28.0\r\nounce,fake,28.0\r\ngram, ounce, 3.0\r\npound,ounce,16.0\r\npound,kilogram,0.454\r\npint,litre,0.568\r\ninch, centimetre,2.5\r\nmile,inch,63360.0\r\n";
var split = "5,ounce,gram".Split(new[] { ',' });
var list = converlist.Split(new[]{"\r\n"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
var matches = list.FindAll(s =>  s.IndexOf(split[1])==-1?false: s.IndexOf(split[2], s.IndexOf(split[1])) != -1);
var conversionLine = matches[0];
Console.WriteLine(conversionLine);
var conversionFactor = decimal.Parse(conversionLine.Split(new[] { ',' })[2]);
var valueToConvert = decimal.Parse(split[0].Trim());
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} {2}s is {1} {3}s", valueToConvert, conversionFactor * valueToConvert, split[1], split[2]));
```

Comment: Thanks, But unfortunately I cant use system.text , But at least it comes in handy for other things.

Comment: why not? its part of C#?  might want to include any artificial limitations in your question

Comment: This is for an assignment where I cant use anything over "system;" and "system.io;". The program works since there are no other matches in "MatchedTwo". Just want to get some other features in, in-case some more get added to the .txt .

Answer (score 0):

Above answer satisfies what you need, however, this will also work.

```
string[] s = { "ounce,gram", "gram,ounce", "pound,carret" };

foreach (string temp in s.Where(x => (x.IndexOf("ounce")>-1) && (x.IndexOf("ounce") < x.IndexOf("gram"))))
            Debug.WriteLine(temp);
```

Comment: if there is a conversion "pound,gram"  this will fail as the index of "ounce" (-1) will be less than "gram"

Comment: Thanks for finding the bug, fixed it.